# Adding your website to free web directories as a link building strategy

Tags: seo, backlinks, link-building

It's been two months since I've launched a website. I recently ran into some websites which list directories of other websites. Some examples of the web directories can be found at `web-directories.ws`.

I was talking with my colleague and he says adding the URL of my website to these kind of websites will negate the effect of other organic real links.

- Does Google consider positive/negative points for these links from web directory websites?
- Do you have any source for your answer to refer to?

I found [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/is-there-a-penalty-in-link-building) asked before on webmasters.SE, but I am asking about many links from a website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO no! What you have done is fine although I'm not sure how often a search engine indexes other search engines, especially the results... In fact, that would be quite an achievement (although there is a comment further down in my answer about directories like DMOZ).

Any way, the consideration is what benefit does it bring more than if you get any negative. EG, why submit to NoOneKnowsAboutThisSearchEnginge.com (made up name of course) when no one has heard of it or use it!?

On the flip side, it only takes one person to use a lesser known search engine to find your site and then post it on a forum which can be indexed by all! Or, to make an enquiry/lead/purchase etc.

It's a common thing, people SEO for Google and seem to forget MSN/Yahoo (or now Bing... I don't think there are any others (even Yahoo is now powered by Bing).

Adding to the index of sites like dmoz is advisable IMO (or any Open Directory / human-edited resource/directory).

Comment: I agree it wouldnt harm, assuming is not your only link building technique. But is it worth the effort? Often manually submitting websites takes 10-15 minutes of valuable time that could be spent otherwise, since the link juice you usually get from those sites is next to nothing :)  (maybe not the case for DMOZ tho) Usually I noticed that for a new site would be good to get a couple in just for the anchor text (assuming you can control anchor text, and you did not already get other links with good anchor). BTW, blekko.com and duckduckgo.com are two excellent engines you forgot to mention :)

Comment: +1 thank you for the other sites. I didn't know of them. I actually use a free tool to do it all for me from http://www.seo-training-course.com/ - it allows submission for many many sites in just a little while and the major players accept it. The others are junk but it's the question - for 15 minutes why wouldn't you. Although I have to agree, I don't think I've seen much advantage from linking to the odd site although every now and then Yahoo Analytics would tell me a search engine I'd never heard of was a referrer! :)